# zeromq: ZMQ_CONFLATE==1 does not stop queues from saving old messages

Tags: caching, zeromq, latency

With ZeroMQ and CPPZMQ 4.3.2, I want to drop old messages for all my sockets including

- PAIR
- Pub/Sub
- REQ/REP

So I use `m_socks[channel].setsockopt(ZMQ_CONFLATE, 1)` on all my sockets before binding/connecting.

### Test

However, when I made the following test, it seems that the old messages are still flushed out on each reconnection. In this test,

- I use a thread to keep sending generated sinewave to a receiver thread
- Every 10 seconds I double the sinewave's frequency
- Then after 10 seconds I stop the process

Below is the pseudocode of the sender

```cpp
// on sender end

auto thenSec = high_resolution_clock::now();
while(m_isRunning) {

    // generate sinewave, double the frequency every 10s or so

    auto nowSec = high_resolution_clock::now();
    if (duration_cast<seconds>(nowSec - thenSec).count() > 10) {
        m_sine.SetFreq(m_sine.GetFreq()*2);
        thenSec = nowSec;
    }
    m_sine.Generate(audio);

    // send to rendering thread

    m_messenger.send("inproc://sound-ear.pair", 
        (const void*)(audio), 
        audio_size, 
        zmq::send_flags::dontwait
    );

}
```

Note that I already use DONTWAIT to mitigate blocking.

On the receiver side I have a `zmq::poller_event` handler that simply receives the last message on event polling.

In the stop sequence I reset the sinewave frequency to its lowest value, say, 440Hz.

### Expected

The expected behaviour would be:

- If I stop both the sender and the receiver after 10s when the frequency is doubled,
- and I restart both,
- then I should see the sinewave reset to 440Hz.

### Observed

But the observed behaviour is that the received sinewave is still of the doubled frequency after restarting the communication, i.e., 880Hz.

### Question

Am I doing it wrong or should I use some kind of killswitch to force drop all messages in this case?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I solved it myself. Kind of.

### Actual solution

I finally realized that the behaviour I want is to flush all messages when I stop the rendering. According to [the official doc](http://wiki.zeromq.org/area:faq)(*How can I flush all messages that are in the ZeroMQ socket queue?*), this can only be achieved by

- set the sockets of both sender's and receiver's `ZMQ_LINGER` option to 0, meaning to keep nothing on closing those sockets;
- closing the sockets on both sender and receiver ends, which also involves bootstrapping pollers and all references to the sockets.

This seems a lot of unnecessary work if I'm to restart rendering my data again, right after the stop sequence. But I found no other way to solve this cleanly.

### Initial effort

It seems to me that `ZMQ_CONFLATE` does not make a difference on `PAIR`. I really have to tweak high water marks on sender and receiver ends using  `ZMQ_SNDHWM` and `ZMQ_RCVHWM`.

However, I said "kind of solved" because tweaking HWM in the end is not the optimal solution for a realtime application,

- having ZMQ_SNDHWM / ZMQ_RCVHWM set to the minimum "1", we still have a sizable latency in terms of realtime.
- Also, the consumer thread could fall into underrun situatioin, i.e.,  perceivable jitters with the lowest HWM.

If I'm not doing anything wrong, I guess the optimal solution would still be shared memory for my targeted scenario. This is sad because I really enjoyed the simplicity of ZMQ's multicast messaging patternsand hate to deal with thread locking littered everywhere.